# How do I provide internet access only to a single Android app?

Tags: applications, internet

- I am currently using Android Smartphone.
- I am currently having internet access for my Android Smartphone.
- I would like to provide internet access to only a single android application, for example: WhatsApp.
- I do understand that I need to provide internet access to some essential default system apps for the functioning of the phone.
- Is it possible to selectively provide internet access to few apps and not for other apps?

Comment: Is your device rooted? Otherwise, this will only be possible using work-arounds (usually via VPN – no other way known to me without root). Be welcome to check with my list of [Internet Firewalls](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_firewall#group_377) for Android :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Opera Max](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.opera.max.global) to restrict per app data access to mobile and Wi-Fi networks. The PlayStore description says it,

> - **Block apps & prevent data leakage:**
>     *Control your apps’ internet usage by blocking apps from running in the background that are using mobile data or Wi-Fi without
>     permission.Blocking apps running in the background conserves battery and minimises your battery usage.*

If you want to restrict only a particular app follow the steps,

- Open Settings menu > Data Usage
- Select the app you want to restrict the data.
- And select "Restrict background data"

If you are on a Wi-Fi network and you want to restrict the app accessing data in the background using your wi-fi connection, do the above steps in the Wi-Fi Tab to restrict the app access to Wi-Fi network too.

Comment: This app would serve my purpose. But, it says that it will set up a VPN Connection which will monitor network traffic. So, is there alternative to this solution, which doesn't network traffic, as it would affect privacy.

Comment: Based on their [privacy statement](http://www.opera.com/help/max/android#private), _Opera Max does not optimize encrypted data. Any data traveling via a secure connection (HTTPS) is sent directly to the site or service your device communicates with. Opera Max never views the contents or proxies information sent through these connections._

Comment: Now that Opera Max is discontinued, do you have any alternative suggestions?  http://www.androidpolice.com/2017/08/14/opera-kills-off-opera-max-delists-play-store-service-will-continue-work-unspecified-time/